# Codeigniter active record left join issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, left-join

I have two  tables 'accounts_transactions' and 'accounts_bills_transactions'.
I have to left join these two using active record of codeigniter.But the names of key columns used to join are different.So I am not getting the key column from the left table in the output .What query should I write to get the key column from the left table included in the result.
My code is

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('accounts_transactions');
    $this->db->join('accounts_bills_transactions', 'accounts_transactions.id = accounts_bills_transactions.transaction_id','left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

So, as you see the key columns used to join here are , id from left table and transaction_id from second table.The problem is that I am not getting the id from left table in the result.But I am getting all other columns.I assume the problem is because of difference in column names used to join.ie both the column names are not named 'id'  .So how can I get the id from left table included in the  result.

Comment: Is this correct? accounts_transactions.id = accounts_transactions.transaction_id, wouldn't it be accounts_transactions.id = accounts_bills_transactions.transaction_id,you're joining on the same table...

Comment: yes that was a typo the query i need is  accounts_transactions.id = accounts_bills_transactions.transaction_id and it is generating  ambigouus column error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could alias them:

```
$this->db->select('accounts_transatctions.*, account_transactions.id AS a_id,
                   accounts_bills_transactions.*, 
                   account_bills_transactions.id AS ab_id');
$this->db->from('accounts_transactions');
$this->db->join('accounts_bills_transactions', 'accounts_transactions.id = accounts_transactions.transaction_id','left');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

The two IDs will now be available as `a_id` and `ab_id` (or whatever alias you choose)

**Note:** I'm not sure if you can alias in AR without avoiding escaping (haven't been using CI for a while). Should you get any error for that reason, just pass `false` as second parameter of `$this->db->select()`:

```
$this->db->select('...', false);
```

Comment: You could try listing all the columns in your select. Are you sure, also, that your query is fine? I mean, maybe you don't want a LEFT join...

Comment: I strictly need left join :)

Answer (score 3):

you can try this if you confuse of using $this->where or $this->join

```
$query = $this->db->query("select ......"); 

return $query;
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is so simple. You can use this query

```
$query  =   $this->db
                ->select('at.*')
                ->select('abt.id as abt_id');
                ->from('accounts_transactions at');
                ->join('accounts_bills_transactions abt', 'at.id = abt.transaction_id','left');
                ->get()
                ->result();
```

When same column are used in join it selects only one. You need to give alise to the other column in second table. The best practice is to use a structure like this

```
accounts_transatctions
--------------------------
accounts_transatctions_id
other_columns

accounts_bills_transactions
---------------------------
accounts_bills_transactions_id
accounts_transatctions_id
other_columns
```